# L5.3 - Call route from another route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've a simple **route** into the file `web.php`:

```
Route::get('first/{param?}', [
   'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\MyController@index',
   'as' => 'myControllerIndex'
]);
```

Now, I'd like to create a second route that uses the first route but passing specific params. 
I tried something like this:

```
Route::get('second', function () {
   return file_get_contents(route('myControllerIndex', ['param' => 'book1']));
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a redirect

```
Route::get('second', function () {
   return redirect()->route('myControllerIndex', ['param' => 'book1']);
});
```

Or you can access the controller directly

```
Route::get('second', function () {
   return app('App\Http\Controllers\MyController')->index('book1');
});
```

Comment: ok, thank you! The first one, changes the URL to the user and is not good for me; the second could be a solution... But, is there a way to use the named route? something like: ```app('myControllerIndex')->index('book1');``` This avoid to rewrite two times the Controller path.

Comment: Not without using a redirect as far as I know.